# Mapping on CF Localhost Showing 404

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I set up a mapping to run Canvas (CF-based wiki) on my machine. I have the following mapping in the CF Administrator; The physical location of the folder is correct, and the port number is accurate.

```
Logical Path     Directory Path
------------     --------------
/canvaswiki      C:\ColdFusion9\canvaswiki
```

When I type `http://localhost:8500/canvaswiki/`, I get a 404

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /canvaswiki/

I restarted CF's service to make sure that wasn't the issue, but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you sure about that physical path? `C:\ColdFusion9` is the root of the server app, but the webroot is typically `C:\Coldfusion9\wwwroot`.

Comment: You are talking about two different things. ColdFusion mappings apply only to pages that ColdFusion processes with the `cfinclude` and `cfmodule` tags. Your example implies that you want a virtual directory (defined on your web server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access `http://localhost:8500/canvaswiki/` from your browser, place the `canvaswiki` folder under `C:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot`. The full path will be `C:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\canvaswiki`.

[Using the Built-in Web Server](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Installing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cdec18c28-7ffc.html)

Comment: I had thought mapping was for virtual directories, not just for `cfmodule` and `cfinclude`.

Comment: Virtual directories tell your web server where to find the files. Mappings tell ColdFusion where to find the files. In this case it's confusing because ColdFusion is acting as both the web server and the application server.